# Is it possible to make 3 Legged OAuth in Google Functions

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-cloud-functions, autodesk-forge, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am developing a ChatBot using Dialogflow. I will integrate it with Autodesk Forge API which needs 3 legged OAuth. I am using Dialogflow fulfillment which is a google cloud function (serverless). I am sending a URL for authentication after the user signs up, it turns to callback URL  with URL + code. Is there a way to catch this parameter in URL in a serverless system like Google Cloud Functions.

(I am using node.js).

Comment: Have you taken a look at [1]? Perhaps after completing it, it can brainstorm some ideas. Furthermore, you need to take a look at [2] and [3] when you post questions in stackoverflow because your question is not answerable. You can look at the answer of [3] in the bullet section for a reason.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/community/tutorials/cloud-functions-oauth-gmail
[2] https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
[3] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Autodesk Forge side, you will need to use OAuth with implicit grant, which returns the `access_token` as part of the URL. [See this tutorial](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/oauth/v2/tutorials/get-3-legged-token-implicit/).